# How to create a TextBox which has a button inside it in windows store app c++

Tags: c#, c++, textbox, windows-store-apps

In windows store app i see many textbox control which has button / image inside it like search control which has search image in it. I want to make it.I am new in windows store app please help me. In below links i give some TextBox of other windows store app.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ouejxvWWAGZHNRR0RzRFpQZU0/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ouejxvWWAGaThIX3NoNG9feWs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Allow access to your images.

Comment: Yes i give access to my images.